# Python 3 len() function for Unicode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tamil

When we believe Python 3 got everything right on Unicode I am surprised while I faced this situation.

```
>>> amma = "அம்மா"
>>> amma
'அம்மா'
>>> len(amma)
5
```

Apparently the Tamil string `"அம்மா"` has 3 letters, A return value of 5 for `len("அம்மா")` in no way can be accepted or appreciated.

How are the other Dravidian or Brahmic scripts solve this issue to get the right string length?

Edit #1:
Considering the comment of @joey this question can be rephrased as below.

**How to calculate the grapheme length in Python?**

We know Swift or Perl6 does this by default

```
  2> let amma = "அம்மா".characters.count
amma: Distance = 3
```

Comment: @Mijago: Nope, it won't.

Comment: The [grapheme](https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/) package on pypi seems to do what you want.  I don't believe there's an easy solution using only the tools in the standard libarary (though the unicodedata module's tools might be useful, depending on your needs).

Answer (score 2):

It may have 3 letters, but it has 5 characters:

```
$ charinfo 'அம்மா'
U+0B85 TAMIL LETTER A [Lo]
U+0BAE TAMIL LETTER MA [Lo]
U+0BCD TAMIL SIGN VIRAMA [Mn]
U+0BAE TAMIL LETTER MA [Lo]
U+0BBE TAMIL VOWEL SIGN AA [Mc]
```

If you need to be more specific then you will need to only count the number of characters that are in the Letter category.

Comment: More precisely: 3 graphemes, but 5 code points. Counting graphemes in a string seems to be a bit complicated in Python, though (can't find any good samples).

Comment: @Joey Thou soundeth well informed. This is driving me nuts now :(

Comment: You can use [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to strip out anything you don't want, but the hard part is figuring out what you do want in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Package

```
pip install Open-Tamil
```

Code

```
from tamil import utf8
amma = "அம்மா"
letters = utf8.get_letters(amma)
print(len(letters))
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code only count the characters and ignores unicode marks (using standard [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module).

```py
import re
amma = "அம்மா"
len(re.findall("[ஃ-ஹ]", amma))
```

Below is the fastest way to get letters counts in unicode (using the third-party [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module).

```py
import regex
amma = "அம்மா"
len(regex.findall('\p{L}\p{M}*', amma))
```